# Search through arrays to find seperate instances of a word

Tags: c++, search, dynamic-arrays

This is an assignment in my advanced C++ class, we're going over pointers and dynamically allocated arrays, though that doesn't seem to be where my trouble lies...

Function header, Quote, Words, and Count are the important arrays, NumWords just holds a count of how many elements are in the Quote array.

```
void CountWords ( char ** Quote, char **& Words, int *& Count, int NumWords )
{
```

Variables and such, some of the arrays are being passed by pointer from main.

```
    char ** Temp = nullptr;
    int * ITemp = nullptr;
    int WordCount = 0;
    int QuoteCount = 0;
```

What follows is a priming read for the For loop coming up.  I'm creating two dynamically allocated arrays, one to store a new found instances of a word in the Quote array, and another to store a count of how many times that word appeared in the Quote array.  All this seems to be working fine, but I don't like how large everything is (Code Bloat) any advice to get this started differently would be excellent.

First dynamic array for char's.

```
Temp = new char * [WordCount + 1];
    for (int z = 0; z < WordCount; z++)
    {
        Temp[z] = Words[z];
    }
Temp[WordCount] = new char[ strlen( Quote[WordCount]) +1  ];
strcpy( Temp[WordCount], Quote[WordCount] );
delete [] Words;
Words = Temp;
```

Second dynamic array for int's.

```
ITemp = new int [ WordCount + 1 ];
    for (int z = 0; z < WordCount; z++)
    {
        ITemp[z] = Count[z];
    }
ITemp[WordCount] = 0;
delete [] Count;
Count = ITemp;
```

This for loop is supposed to use the new value in the **char array, iterate through Quote to find other instances of that value, and increments Count at the same index number for that element.  Seems to work...

```
for (int j = 0; j < NumWords; j++)
{
    if (_stricmp( Words[ WordCount ], Quote[j]) == 0 )
    {
    Count[ WordCount ]++;
    }
}
```

Counters for how many words have been stored in the Words array, and where in the Quote array the function is.

```
WordCount++;
QuoteCount++;
```

This is where things start to go wonky...

```
for (int i = 0; i < NumWords; i++)
{

//Right here is where the program breaks, after the second iteration of this
//For-loop.  What happens is the loop counter (i) increments to 2 shortly 
//before Words[2] gets created.  I've tried decrementing i inside the If,
//where QuoteCount gets incremented, but that causes an out-of-bounds error
//on the Quote array on the last iteration.

//Check to see if Quote value is in Words
if (_stricmp( Quote[ QuoteCount ], Words[ i ]) == 0 )
{
    //If true, move on to next element in Quote array.
    QuoteCount++;
}

//If false, write Quote value to Words
else
{
        Temp = new char * [WordCount + 1];
        for (int z = 0; z < WordCount; z++)
        {
            Temp[z] = Words[z];
        }
        Temp[WordCount] = new char[ strlen( Quote[WordCount]) +1  ];
        strcpy( Temp[WordCount], Quote[WordCount] );
        delete [] Words;
        Words = Temp;

 //Create new array element in Count to track new value in Words
        ITemp = new int [ WordCount + 1 ];
        for (int z = 0; z < WordCount; z++)
        {
            ITemp[z] = Count[z];
        }
        ITemp[WordCount] = 0;
        delete [] Count;
        Count = ITemp;


//Check Quote for other instances of Word
        for (int j = 0; j < NumWords; j++)
        {
            if (_stricmp( Words[ WordCount ], Quote[j]) == 0 )
            {
            Count[ WordCount ]++;
            }//if
        }//for
//Increment word counter, indicating a new word was stored.

        WordCount++;

    }//else
}//for
}//function
```

I feel this has become far more complicated than it needs to be.  I tried nesting For-loops to begin with, but I couldn't seem to get that working either.  Another thing is, once it copies a word from Quote to Words, it shouldn't copy that word again.

Also, general input on code quality and such would be appricated.  I'm striving to become a software engineer later in life, and I like to be the best at what I do, so I need to learn as much as I can all the time.

Comment: Are you prohibited from using standard containers like `string` and `vector`?

Comment: No `vectors`, we haven't gotten to them yet.  As for `string` do you mean `cstring`?  I suppose not, the `strstr`, `strtok` and, `strchr` functions were introduced in the chapter also.

Comment: No I meant `std::string`, but it looks like your stuck doing things the hard way for now.

Comment: Then hard way it is.  Gotta learn the basics before learning the cool stuff, right?

If I could figure out the incrementing problem, I think the rest of it should work.  Unless the incrementing problem is a symptom of an underlying problem that I can't see.

Comment: Can you provide sample function arguments?

Comment: The quote it currently processes is a quote from Bill Cosby.  It's stored in a .txt file that gets read into the program in a different function. The quote is:  **I don't know the key to success, but the key to failure is trying to please everybody.**  After getting read in, a fucntion is used to strip trailing punctuation, in this case the period and comma, before being sent to this function for analysis.

Comment: Oh, and Words and Count are declared to `nullptr` when they are passed to this function.  They will be getting values here before returning to `main`.

Comment: So I'm right in thinking that `Words` will hold the list of unique words, and `Count` will have the respective count of each of those words?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  It seems a good portion of my class is struggling with this, and the other portion is fighting with the dynamic arrays.  I _think_ I get the arrays, I just don't get this comparison.

Comment: What is the content of `Words` and `Count` when the function is called and why are you deleting them?

Comment: They are initialized to `nullptr`, then passed here when the function is called.  The `delete` is part of resizing them.  The example in our book shows a temp array being created with room for one more element, the values of each element being copied to the temp array, the new value being written in the new element in the temp array, then the old array being removed and the pointer being reassigned to the temp array, so it becomes the new array.

Comment: Hang on just realized the `Temp[z] = Words[z];` loop won't run, but then why is it even in there, it will never run, ever.

Comment: The first instance of it won't, it makes note of that in our textbook, so in the priming run I guess it doesn't need to be there.  But as values are added to the elements inside the `For-loop` and `WordCount` starts incrementing, that little loop is needed to keep the values in the arrays as they grow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue is you seem to want to step through the quote using `i`, but at the same time you are using it to index `Words`. A more logical way to do things is to check each word of the quote against the existing words you have already copied into `Words`, and either incrementing the count or inserting the word accordingly. You can also take advantage of the fact that there will be at most `NumWords` in `Words` and allocate enough memory at the start of the function:

```
void CountWords(char const** Quote, char**& Words, int*& Count, int NumWords)
{
  Words = new char*[NumWords];
  Count = new int[NumWords];

  int words = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < NumWords; ++i) {

    int j = 0;
    for (; j < words; ++j) {

      if (!strcmp(Quote[i], Words[j])) { // Duplicate word
        ++Count[j];
        break;
      }
    }

    if (j == words) { // New word found
      Words[words] = new char[strlen(Quote[i]) + 1]{};
      strcpy(Words[words], Quote[i]);
      Count[words] = 1;
      words++;
    }
  }

  Count[words] = 0;
}

int main()
{
  char const* quote[] = {"Hello", "world", "hello", "world"};
  char** words;
  int* count;
  CountWords(quote, words, count, 4);

  for (int i = 0; count[i]; ++i) {
    std::cout << words[i] << ' ' << count[i] << '\n';
    delete[] words[i];
  }

  delete[] words;
  delete[] count;      
}
```

In any case array / pointer shenanigans are hard to read and error-prone, there is hardly any code here (or your original code) that could be called "c++" aside from `new`, it's c with a dash of c++. The entire app can be more easily written in modern c++ like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

int main()
{
  std::string word;
  std::unordered_map<std::string, int> map;

  while (std::cin >> word)
    ++map[word];

  for (auto const& w : map)
    std::cout << w.first << " : " << w.second << '\n';
}
```

And used like this: `app < textfile.txt`

Comment: This seems to work perfectly.  I had to put a `For-loop` right at the start to write 0 to all the elements of the new Count array.  Other than that, fantastic!  Thank you so much.  I was about to pull my hair out...

Comment: @Teravian Good catch! Goes to show how easy it is to get this stuff wrong. Another option is changing `Count[words]++;` to `Count[words] = 1;` instead. You can also zero arrays as follows: `Count = new int[NumWords]{};`